# Working with data exceeded memory

Tags: python, database, memory

I have a data structure which represents a list of objects and links between them. Each objects owns a dict with properties which can even be nested Python objects.

Occationally these objects exceed the available memory, due to sheer number or sometimes due to individual large properties.

Is there an easy way to still handle such data without memory exceptions?

If I had only strings a properties I could think about graph data bases, but maybe there is something simpler that lets me keep my Python data structure.

Comment: You either need to find a more efficient way to represent them, process them in bits, or store them on disk. Which of those makes sense, and how to do it, really depends on what the data are and what you're trying to do with them.

Comment: Adding to Thomas' comment I would suggest abstracting the "links" part of the data into its own object and keep that in memory only. If that is at all possible, so as to keep the "large properties" on disk.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 "real" solutions and 2 "literally what you want" solution:

1. Modify the schema, so you aren't keeping giant pieces of data you don't need; perhaps you are using a database and don't need to retrieve those pieces of data in the query.
2. Modify your goals: maybe you don't really need to process such things.
3. Break up processing into smaller chunks, making sure you free up unused objects to be garbage-collected (by letting go of all references).
4. Buy more RAM.

The two solutions that literally do what you want, without buying more RAM, will need to use the hard disk. Thus, they will be incredibly slow. If however your data size is vast (hundreds of gigabytes), and you **have** to go through all the data, this may be your only option (a flash-drive may provide nice speedup, but excessive writes will soon wear it down).

1. Increase the size of your virtual memory. (In Linux, this is done by increasing the size of your swap partition, or adding more swap partitions.)
2. Break up processing into smaller chunks, unloading stuff from RAM back to disk via garbage-collecting, even though you may need it again.

Comment: OK, so I suppose I will need to store selected properties of the objects on harddrive. Say I have an ID for each object. What's the fastest way to access the outsources properties from the harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* just install more RAM ;-)

This is by far the easiest solution (though I'm not sure how viable it is in your particular case), and may even be the cheapest (keep in mind the cost of changing code).

Just an option to be aware of...

Comment: Well, installing more RAM is a solution I can think of myself and I wouldn't ask for it ;) Also storing stuff on the harddrive somehow I could probably also figure out myself. But is there some database like framework that would help to do it more or less transparently?

Comment: @Gerenuk: This is the most transparent solution I could think of (besides increasing your virtual RAM (I'm assuming Windows here) and having lots of disk swaps -- which I suppose is technically a transparent way of using the disk as a backing store for too-large objects in memory). Anything else will likely require significant code changes -- I'm afraid you'll need to share the specifics of your model for more detailed answers.

Comment: Well, the model is many Objects with a dict which stores the properties. Mostly it's strings or numbers, but occationally lists and maybe more in the future. All objects keep a reference to linked objects which is basically a list of references. Hmm, so I could try to store either selected properties or the link table on the harddrive. Is there any tool that can help? Actually first I thought about some database like solution that might keep my objects on the harddrive transparently.

Comment: @Gerenuk: You may want to take a look at [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) or [Cerealizer](http://home.gna.org/oomadness/en/cerealizer/index.html) if you haven't already, perhaps in conjunction with a database.

Comment: But with pickle I again can only load everything at once? I somehow need to store many properties on the disk which I need to selectively access by my ID. A database would be an option, but then I need to pack arbitrary python structures?! I suppose that's what you mean. Is there anything ready-made?